# Overloading structs in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

I want to make a very generic pure virtual class i_BIS_Data that will be inherited by unique BIS_Data classes.

```
class i_BIS_Data
{
public:

i_BIS_Data(void) { }
virtual ~i_BIS_Data( void ) { }

  virtual void setData(bis_data data) = 0;
};
```

I want all my children of i_BIS_Data to define the bis_data struct as they all will be different. I expect my child class to look similar to the following:

```
class BIS_0192_Aircraft_ID_Data : i_BIS_Data
{
  public:

  struct bis_data
  {
   UInt16  acid; 
   UInt16  parity; 
  };

  void setData(bis_data data){   m_data.parity = data.parity; 
                             m_data.acid   = data.acid; }
}
```

When I try to compile a class that uses BIS_0192_Aircraft_ID_Data, I get the following error: error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'bis_data'. I believe its because I haven't defined bis_data within the parent class.

So is it possible to "overload" the structure and allow multiple children classes to define what bis_data is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 template<typename BIS_DATA_T>
 class i_BIS_Data
 {
      typedef BIS_DATA_T bis_data;
      ...
      virtual void setData(bis_data data) = 0;
 };

 struct bis_0192_data
 {
    UInt16  acid; 
    UInt16  parity; 
 };

 class BIS_0192_Aircraft_ID_Data : public i_BIS_Data<bis_0192_data>
 {
   public:
   void setData(bis_data data){   m_data.parity = data.parity; 
                         m_data.acid   = data.acid; }
 };
```

This should work, however subclasses of `i_BIS_Data<XX>` with different types for XX are incompatible.

Comment: +1. You beat me by 16 seconds with a template-based solution. This latter problem (non-common base classes) can be fixed by making the template class derive from some non-template class.

Comment: This doesn't allow him to use a i_BIS_Data * to refer to any of the subtypes since the originally problem stated that all subtypes had a differenct structure definition. David's solution is probably as good as it's going to get.

Comment: @WayneTanner: They AREN'T subtypes, because they violate LSP.

Comment: Awesome, I'll try this out and let everyone know how well it works.

Comment: Ok, derived types then to use the more correct technical term.

Comment: @WayneTanner the question gives no reason or description of the problem that the code should solve, so I fulfilled the only given requirement. I do know that there are likely better solutions for the underlying problem, however I do not know what problem that is.

Comment: @josefx Thanks, your answer was perfect!  

Sorry if the problem was not very clear. The reason for the parent class is to force a standard interface. I have no plans to use i_BIS_Data * besides casting it to the appropriate child class.

Answer (score 2):

No.

In OOP theory, arguments of function overloads can be contravariant and the return type can be covariant.

In C++, covariant return type is allowed, but parameter types are invariant.

What you're asking for is covariance on the argument type, which is theoretically wrong as well as not allowed in C++.

I suggest you read about the Liskov Substitution Principle.  It will help immensely as you design class hierarchies with inheritance.

Comment: Is there a possible way to define setData as generic as possible such that all children can usefully inherit the interface?

Comment: @Kat: Show how you expect to call the function, given a `vector<i_BIS_Data*>`...  When you try to do that, you'll realize why it makes no sense to include this function as part of the interface.

Comment: I'm not planning on calling the i_BIS_Data function - the class cannot be instantiated. It's the child class that should contain the procedure to perform the function.

Comment: @Kat: That's a pointer in my comment, not an instantiation.  Why do you think you need an interface and virtual functions at all?

Answer (score 1):

```
class i_BIS_Data
{
  public:

  i_BIS_Data(void) { }
  virtual ~i_BIS_Data( void ) { }

  virtual void setData(void* data) = 0;
};


class BIS_0192_Aircraft_ID_Data : i_BIS_Data
{
  public:

  struct bis_data
  {
   UInt16  acid; 
   UInt16  parity; 
  };

  bis_data m_data;

  void setData(void* data)
  {   
      m_data = *(bis_data*)data;
      // m_data.parity = data.parity; 
      // m_data.acid   = data.acid; 
  }
};
```

Example:

```
BIS_0192_Aircraft_ID_Data::bis_data data;

data.acid = 7;
data.parity = 8;

BIS_0192_Aircraft_ID_Data c;

c.setData((void*)&data);
```

Comment: Thanks. If I the answer above wasn't posted, I would have used this solution. I was trying to stay away from void pointers. :)